# `systemctl hibernate` not executed on crontab script

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, cron, hibernate

I have a script that verifies the battery level using acpi and if it's below certain threshold it should lock the machine and hibernate. The script is executed every minute using crontab

The problem is that the machine gets locked but never hibernates.

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
acpi -b | awk -F'[,:%]' '{print $2, $3}' | {
    read -r status capacity

    if [ "$status" = Discharging -a "$capacity" -lt 10 ]; then
        echo 'Success' >> /tmp/low;
        logger "Critical battery threshold";
        DISPLAY=:0 i3lock -t -i $(ls -d ~/.wallpapers/* | shuf | head -n 1);
        echo 'Locked' >> /tmp/low;
        systemctl hibernate;
    fi
}
```

The `/tmp/low` log file shows the following:

```
$ cat /tmp/low 
Success
Locked
Success
Locked
Success
Locked
```

I tried to directly run a similar script (Without the ACPI check) and it worked perfectly

The testing script:

```
#!/bin/sh
acpi -b | awk -F'[,:%]' '{print $2, $3}' | {
    read -r status capacity

        echo 'Success' >> /tmp/low;
        logger "Critical battery threshold";
        DISPLAY=:0 i3lock -t -i $(ls -d ~/.wallpapers/* | shuf | head -n 1);
        echo 'Locked' >> /tmp/low;
        systemctl hibernate;
}
```

Same testing script was run using `at` but it didn't hibernate the machine. Any ideas why crontab can't execute `systemctl hibernate`?

Comment: The `systemctl` command takes two parameters: the COMMAND (i.e., 'start', 'stop', 'status', etc.) and the NAME of the service to execute the COMMAND on. In your test instance , it's missing the COMMAND part of that setup.

Comment: @ThomasN This is not the case, running `systemctl hibernate` from terminal works perfectly fine. The script also works fine, except when tools such as `cron` or `at` runs it

Comment: I stand corrected... should have read the manual pages a little further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. Apparently the problem was in the `polkit` package that defines the policies for users to shutdown, reboot, suspend, hibernate, etc

As I had no rule file in `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d` the default is not to allow users to hibernate or suspend the machine while a user is logged in (I believe the problem here is that I'm locking the machine before hibernating, and therefore there is an open session)

To solve it I had to create the file `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/99-allow-hibernate-on-low-battery.rules` with the following content:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions") {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

After that, `cron` and `at` can hibernate the machine correctly